# how to store the procedure output parameters in a temporary table without an anonymous block?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to store a procedure output parameters in postgres without create an annonymous block?

Imagine the scenario:

```sql
create or replace procedure test(in one integer, in two integer, inout three integer)
language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
    three:=one+two;
end
$$
```

If I call it like this:

```sql
call test(2,2,null);
```

The result is 4, but if I try to add the result to a temporaty table like this:

```sql
create temp table store(a int);
insert into store (a) 
call test(2,2,null);
```

I have the error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "call"
LINE 15: call test(2,2,null);
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 253

To avoid the do statement (because I have to do this in plain sql), I don't know how to store the output variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use a function not a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(one integer, two integer)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    three integer;
begin
    three:=one+two;
    return three;
end
$function$
;

select * from test(2,2);
 test 
------
    4

create temp table store(a int);

insert into store (a) select * from test(2,2);

select * from store;
 a 
---
 4
```

A function can return a value in a `select`.

Comment: There is a problem also with that solution, I'm just calling to test the sored procedure, so the stored procedure should remain intact, it came to my mind also to wrap the stored procedure call within a function, but it should be in plain sql because its a test script running by jdbc, so I'm running out of ideas.